# How can I get audio over Displayport?

Tags: release-loki, sound, audio

I'm currently running elementary OS Loki and I have my monitor connected via Displayport 1.4

On other Linux distributions (Solus) I am able to play sound on my monitor.

On elementary OS, there is nothing to click in the Output section of the Sound setting.

When I type `aplay -l` this is what I see

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pavucontrol`, more informations [here](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/)

The next steps work for me:

- Open a terminal
- type `alsamixer`
- with the card **HDA ATI SB with chip Realtek ALC892**, turn auto-mute to disabled.
- After that i'd install Pulse Audio Volume control.

`$ sudo apt install pavucontrol`

- Open it **Pulse Audio Volume Control**
- In Configuration tab you can see the **ATI HDMI Digital Setereo and Internal Audio**.
- Select to Internal Audio: **Stereo Analog Duplex (Estéreo analógico duplex).**
- In **Pulse Audio Volume**, select Ouput devices, and for Internal Analog Stereo select: analg headphones.

**Important:** You must have installed the ATI drivers first. D Atonaltzin

---

## System information

- Motherboard Gigabyte GA-880GM-USB3 (realtek ALC892 audio integrated)
- AMD Phenom II
- 4GB RAM
- Ati Radeon RX460 2GB graphics card.alsamix

Comment: If I go to the configuration tab inside Pulse Audio Control, every option says (unplugged) to the right of it